# What is the result of running `chmod 7` on a file?

Tags: files, chmod

I know `chmod 777` allows **read**, **write**, and **execute** for *user*, *group*, and *others*

but what if I just do `chmod 7`?

Is that only `rwx` for the *user*?

Comment: Did you actually try it yourself before asking this question?

Comment: Also visit [this](http://askubuntu.com/q/518259/256099)

Comment: In octal, 7 == 007.

Answer (score 21):

Ramesh's answer is perfectly accurate, but I wanted to chime in and provide a more in depth explanation of file modes.

While numbers like `755` and `777` may seem special and only mean something for file modes, they're actually pretty basic.

These numbers are actually octal numbers. Decimal numbers are base-10, hex numbers are base-16, binary is base-2, and octal numbers are base-8. Meaning that as you count, you go `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 20 ...`. So the number `007`, is just octal `7`. The octal number `755` is just a number, and is equivalent to `493` in decimal.
Now how you differentiate an octal number from any other base is that octal numbers are prefixed with a `0`. So to say `755` is octal, you should really refer to it as `0755`. The `chmod` command just assumes that all input numbers are octal since that is the most common way of referring to file modes.

Now, why do file modes use octal? Well first we need to understand that the mode is just a bitmask that looks like this:

```
111111111111 - 12 binary bits
============
           1 - Other execute
          1  - Other write
         1   - Other read
        1    - Group execute
       1     - Group write
      1      - Group read
     1       - User execute
    1        - User write
   1         - User read
  1          - Sticky bit
 1           - Set group ID
1            - Set user ID
```

Note that there are 3 bits for each of "other", "group", & "user". Binary `111` is `7`, which is the highest single digit octal value. So by using octal numbering, each of the other, group, & user permissions gets a single digit, plus an extra digit for the sticky+setuid+setgid.

So with this, we can go back to your original question of "what is `chmod 7`"?
Well, now that we know it's just a octal number, and that it's just a bitmask, we can figure this out. Octal `7` is binary `111`. Using the above bit positions, we can determine that this sets all 3 of the 'other' bits, granting 'other' execute, read, & write access. And since this is just a number, all the other bits are 0, and become unset.

Answer (score 19):

It's the other way around. It will give `rwx` permission for *others*.

```
touch samplefile
ls -l samplefile
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ramesh ramesh 0 Oct 16 22:29 samplefile
```

Now after I execute the command, I get the output as,

```
chmod 7 samplefile
ls -l samplefile
-------rwx 1 ramesh ramesh 0 Oct 16 22:29 samplefile
```

From man page of `chmod`,

> numeric mode is from one to  four  octal  digits  (0-7),  derived  by
>    adding up the bits with values 4, 2, and 1.  **Omitted digits are assumed
>    to be leading zeros.**

Now, we can verify the same by executing the command as,

```
chmod 47 samplefile
ls -l samplefile
----r--rwx 1 ramesh ramesh 0 Oct 16 22:29 samplefile
```

As we can see, with `chmod 47` on a file will give **read** permission for *group* and **read**,**write** and **execute** permission for *others*.

Comment: Think of it as 007.

Comment: @khadija Or 0007.

Comment: @Michael Or 07.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Indeed, but what most people don't consider is that the normally-three-octal-digits permission value is actually *four* octal digits, as shown by Patrick's answer.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling: Yes I think you missed my joke, which is rooted in the fact that the actual number of digits _does not matter_ as long as you use the correct base and specify the correct value.